# How to retrieve data from within a node name?

Tags: mysql, xquery

I am able to retrieve the data between the nodes, but not from in the node itself.  I searched far and wide, but can't seem to find a solution for this.

My XML looks like the following:

[image]

And this XML is saved inside a nvarchar column called fileXML in SQL (Server 2008R2).
[image]

I want to retrieve the History Date, which is inside the node name.

My current code which is retrieving the "18" from the node value is the following:
                            , `fileXML.value('(/commands/command/measure/categories/category/components/component/history)[1]', 'varchar(100)')  as HisDate`

Like you can see on the picture above, this is working.
But I can't seem to retrieve the info from within the node.

I searched on the web, and tried several things like:

```
fileXML.value('(/commands/command/measure/categories/category/components/component/history.name)[1]', 'varchar(100)')  as HisDate

fileXML.value('(/commands/command/measure/categories/category/components/component/history/local-name)[1]', 'varchar(100)')  as HisDate

fileXML.value('(/commands/command/measure/categories/category/components/component/history/local-name(.))[1]', 'varchar(100)')  as HisDate
```

Where the first 2 became a NULL value, and the last one gave an error message that a function is not supported.  I can give much more example on what I tried, but this would make the post a bit messy.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` is an attribute of the history element. So your path should be

```
/commands/command/measure/categories/category/components/component/history/@date
```

Untested as you supplied the XML as a picture.

Comment: This worked like a charm.
Thanks a lot!  (I added the XML as a picture, since I couldn't paste it as code, not sure what I should have picked instead).

Comment: Well done @chrisis for making sense of this question, despite its use of completely non-standard terminology. GertDeWilde, you will find it much easier to google for information or to ask questions that people understand if you learn the terminology and concepts. For example "18" is not "between the nodes" it IS a node (a text node); in the lexical XML it is between two tags (a start tag and an end tag), but XQuery is not concerned with lexical XML, it is concerned with a node tree.